# What does ":1", ":2" in SQL mean?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking at a sql statement that looks like this:

```
...
AND col2_.col_date >= :1
AND col2_.col_date <= :2
...
```

and I have no idea what :1 and :2 does??

Can someone enlighten me,

Thanks,
:)

Comment: "Which SQL"? I am guessing place-holders of sorts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the colon sign ":" do in a SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177978/what-does-the-colon-sign-do-in-a-sql-query)

Comment: postgres sql, so place-holders can be in numbers?

Comment: @OMG Ponies  I actually read that post and I thought there is a difference between :number and :string/name

Comment: @Aion: No, IME with Oracle BIND variables - they don't support reuse, so it doesn't matter if they are named the same or not.

Comment: @OMG Ponies Sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean by, "it doesn't matter if they are named the same or not" So, it doesn't matter what the bind variable is named even though it is just a number?

Comment: BIND variables work of ordinal position in relation to all the BIND variables in the query, starting at the first characters of the statement (IE: SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) -- naming them is only informational to those who support them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They're placeholders in a parametrized query, waiting for the program to come along and supply the parameters.

Answer (score 4):

There are parameters, specified when running the query - rather than having the date as text directly in the query, they're parameters injected when the query is run.  What you're seeing are the first and second placeholders...the syntax varies between servers and providers.  For example sometimes you'll see them names instead of numbered, etc.

Comment: @pst - Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

These are placeholders, but not in SQL, only in your programming language that constructs the SQL-string. In SQL (PostgreSQL anyway) you have to use numbered placeholders $1, $2, etc. Check the PostgreSQL-manual for [PREPARE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-prepare.html) or the PHP-manual for [pg_query_params()](http://nl.php.net/pg_query_params).