# What does a colon (':') mean in SQL syntax?

Tags: sql, database, syntax, oracle11g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the colon sign “:” do in a SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177978/what-does-the-colon-sign-do-in-a-sql-query)

Simple SQL question:
What does `:` stand for?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE Employee_column = :P_EmplId;
```

The `:` isn't exactly easy to google when you don't know what this is called. Even searching here didn't help. I'm using Oracle 11g if that makes any difference.

Comment: Is it used in a php procedure?

Comment: Never seen that before.. I've seen := which is equivalent to =

Comment: it's a select statement used in ASP.NET webpage. Not PHP, nor  stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The answer i was looking for is there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a [bind variable](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html):

> A placeholder in a SQL statement that must be replaced with a valid
>   value or value address for the statement to execute successfully. By
>   using bind variables, you can write a SQL statement that accepts
>   inputs or parameters at run time. The following example shows a query
>   that uses v_empid as a bind variable:

Comment: Fix for broken link (needs https): https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you took the query from a template. It is meant to be processed with php's MDB2 sql framework. The ":" (colon) signals a placeholder in the statement, meant to be replaced when the query is executed.

Comment: Yes, i got it now. It's a placeholder for input that is in the textbox on the website.