# What does 'colon' mean in SQL under WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have SQL function, it is not written by me.

I am having hard time understanding, what does following condition mean?
specifically `:key` and `||cLF||'`.

```
WHERE  ' WHERE 1=1 '
       ||cLF||' AND   f.key = :key '
       ||cLF||' AND   i.flag = 0'
       ||cLF||' AND   r.flag = 0'
```

Comment: Do you mean "colon" instead of semicolon?

Comment: http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html

Comment: @JoãoSilva Thanks for link. and jimp Fixed thanks, I tried best to not have any silly errors while asking question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the colon sign ":" do in a SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177978/what-does-the-colon-sign-do-in-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `||` operator is a [string concatenation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278189/what-is-the-string-concatenation-operator-in-oracle).  So it looks like the code is building a `WHERE` clause using conditions specified by `cLF`.  Though I'm not entirely sure why they're tacking on `cLF` three times there.

The `:key` syntax refers to a parameter in a parameterized query.  Its value will be passed in when the SQL statement you're building is actually run.

Comment: `CLF` is set as Constant `CONSTANT varchar2(1)  := chr(10);`

Comment: mike thanks for explaining and helpful link, so in that link, can you please explain what `'Mr '` selects?

Comment: also in my case `CLF` is it changing the type?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about *what 'Mr ' selects*.  Can you elaborate?  `cLF` is just adding linefeeds to your statement, they really have no purpose except for readability.  Perhaps the statement is being logged somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The query you have pasted is a part of a dynamically constructed SQL statement.
Semicolon here points to a bind-place holder, meaning that the actual value for ":key" is passed through an argument and not hard coded.

Read examples on EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.