# PL-SQL bind variables in TCL

Tags: plsql, tcl, trace, bind-variables

Could some one explain in the following TCL source code:

```tcl
set sql "SELECT PROD.KEY || ' {' || PARAMETERS || '}' \
         FROM PRV_PROD_MAPPING PROD \
         WHERE PROD.SERVICE_ID = :service_id \
         AND (PROD.KEY || ' ' || PROD.KEY_VAL) \
         IN (:keys) "
```

what **:service_id** and **:keys** mean. Could I see the values behind by simple trace.
How could I find where these vars are defined?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you've shown is simply the assignment of a string to a variable named` sql`. What does your program do with that string? What mechanism are you using to interact with the database?

Comment: You are right, but that I want to find out is how to see the value behind (:keys). When I try to call $keys, there is no such variable!

Comment: Should I understand these bind variables as a placeholders?

Comment: They are indeed placeholders; how they're filled in depends on the driver. Those that conform to the TDBC specification will use variables or a supplied dictionary (as Glenn's answer shows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it using traces:

```
sys.DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_EV(n_sid, n_serial, 10046, 12, '');
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Trace started: ' || to_char(SYSDATE,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not TCL its an SQL query embedded in a TCL string, specifically one that [binds a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177978/what-does-the-colon-sign-do-in-a-sql-query), which is then assigned to a normal TCL variable

As glenn points out, on its own this snippet of TCL does very little. presuembly somewhere in your program you actually connect to a DB and pass it a query from this string and some other variables

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [TDBC](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TdbcCmd/contents.htm), you might have

```tcl
# assume the connection has already occured and is named "db"
set sql "SELECT ... WHERE a.b=:service_id IN (:keys)"
set statement [db prepare $sql]

# get the bind variables' values from the local context:
set service_id 42
set keys [join {key1 key2 key3} ,]
set resultset [$statement execute]

# or, without setting the "service_id" and "keys" variables, 
# provide them as an argument to the execute subcommand
unset service_id keys
set resultset [$statement execute {service_id 24 keys "foo,bar,baz"}]
```

Comment: I'm not very good familiar with tcl, but I think it is using some tcl embedded oracle functions starting with ora*.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out it you just assign a string* to a variable.

More exactly, you assign the following string to a variable called `sql`

```
SELECT PROD.KEY || ' {' || PARAMETERS || '}'  FROM PRV_PROD_MAPPING PROD  WHERE PROD.SERVICE_ID = :service_id  AND (PROD.KEY || ' ' || PROD.KEY_VAL)  IN (:keys)
```

The values of `:service_id` and `:keys` are bound values that are passed later (In a `oraplexec` statement probably).

`||` is string concatenation in SQL. So `PROD.KEY || ' {' || PARAMETERS || '}'` could be `PRODKEY {PARAMETERS}`.

*Everything is a string