# For symfony2, when I see some codes, there are "something = :something"

Tags: sql, symfony, dql

What does "= :" mean in SQL or DQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the colon sign ":" do in a SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177978/what-does-the-colon-sign-do-in-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a reference to **parameter binding** in DQL.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query

> Note that numeric placeholders start with a ? followed by a number while the named placeholders start with a : followed by a string.

you must then set your parameter with a `->setParameter()` method.

```
$qb->select('u')
   ->from('User', 'u')
   ->where('u.id = :identifier')
   ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC')
   ->setParameter('identifier', 100); // Sets :identifier to 100, and thus we will fetch a user with u.id = 100
```

This is *good practice* when using Doctrine because it is much more secure and prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand this concept!