# Error near LIMIT but only when I use colons

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to run this query:

```
SELECT wins FROM players WHERE auth = '[U:1:123456789]' LIMIT 1;
```

But I get the following error:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

However, when I remove `LIMIT 1` it works.

If I change the query to look like this, it also works:

```
SELECT wins FROM players WHERE auth = '[123456789]' LIMIT 1;
```

I'm very confused, what am I doing wrong? It seems like colons just break the query.

Edit: CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
 `auth` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '< blank >',
 `wins` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`auth`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Your error says you used `LIMIT 0, 25` but your query don't

Comment: @AshrafulIslam - that's something phpMyAdmin does automatically.

Comment: @Martin edited it into the question body.

Comment: @shavit The query you provide seems ok to me.

Comment: Works for me also on Mysql 5.7. My first guess is that phpmyadmin is failing to build the query properly, or it's a character set problem.

Comment: Try and use `utf8` at the outset, if not `utf8mb4` to support emoji. This is a gigantic pain to fix later, so fixing it now helps *immeasurably*.

Comment: It's possible your admin tool is adding a `LIMIT` clause when there's one already there. Does removing `LIMIT 1` resolve the issue?

Comment: does MariaDb use colons (`:`) as special characters that need to be escaped?

Comment: Well, I just investigated further and it did place a double `LIMIT` as long as I have a colon there..  `SELECT wins FROM players WHERE auth = '[U:1:123456789]' LIMIT 1 LIMIT 0, 25` is the query shown by phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @Martin It could be the `:` character is tripping it up and causing it to, or the version being used is from the stone age and is full of bugs. It's not clear from the context of this question, because that query is absolutely fine and yet the error does not match the query.

Comment: Is there some kind of pagination option or default set that causes that `LIMIT` to be injected? I find phpMyAdmin to be pretty feeble compared to a proper SQL tool. I'd strongly recommend using something like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) (free) instead of the PHP front-end.

Comment: @tadman I use PhPMyAdmin and while I definitely has its shortfalls, it's not that bad as to not notice a given `LIMIT`! `:-D`

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I assume it's a phpMyAdmin bug, so I reported it on their GitHub issues page. I'll update this question once I get an answer from the phpMyAdmin developers.

Comment: @shavit what is your version of your SQL and PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: MariaDB is at the latest version from the Ubuntu repositories, phpMyAdmin is 4.6.6.

Comment: @shavit version 10.1.22 or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being an issue with phpMyAdmin's (the client I used to run the queryh) SQL parser.

As of 4.7.1 of phpMyAdmin, it should be fixed.

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/commit/4f85b6d8d3a3ddcf6ff216c116cf305978e9a3d2

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Three</strike> Four options (starting with the most likely):

0) Your version of your SQL Database or your version of PHPMyAdmin is very, very out of date and should be updated ASAP.

1) You're running the SQL on a PHP PDO interface which uses Colons to mark an input variable. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177978/what-does-the-colon-sign-do-in-a-sql-query).

2) MariaDb uses colons as special characters and they need to be properly escaped.

3) Somehow you have two LIMITs (as mentoned by Tadman, that PhpMyAdmin or your own PHP interface is adding a LIMIT) when one is not needed.

Comment: Since when is colon a special character and needs to be escaped?